# $\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\left(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)=1$. Find $(x+y)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> We know that $\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\left(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)=1$. Find the expression $(x+y)$.

**My work so far:**

$$\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\left(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)=1$$
$$\color{red}{\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\cdot}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\left(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)=\color{red}{\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\cdot}1$$
$$-\left(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)=\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$$
$$-\color{red}{\left(y-\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)\cdot}\left(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)=\color{red}{\left(y-\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)\cdot}\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$$
$$1=\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\left(y-\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)$$
*I need help here.*

Comment: See also [Prove that if $({x+\sqrt{x^2+1}})({y+\sqrt{y^2+1}})=1$ then $x+y=0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1118742)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that we have
$$-\left(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)=\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$$ From your third line. Now $$x+y=\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{y^2+1}\tag{1}$$ In the same fashion, we can get$$x+y=\sqrt{y^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+1}\tag{2}$$ Now adding $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$ together gives $x+y=0$. We are done.

Answer (score 6):

$t\mapsto t+\sqrt{t^2+1}$ is a strictly increasing function, hence for each $x$ there is at most one $y$ that makes the equation true. On the other hand, $$(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})(-x+\sqrt{x^2+1})=(x^2+1)-x^2=1$$ suggests that $y=-x$ is a valid such choice. We conclude that $x+y=0$.