# How to prove that $(x+ {\sqrt{1+x^2}} ) ( y+ {\sqrt {1+y^2}}) = 1$ if $(x+ {\sqrt{1+y^2}} ) ( y+ {\sqrt {1+x^2}}) = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals, quadratic-forms

Let $x,y$ be real numbers such that :

$(x+ {\sqrt{1+y^2}} ) ( y+ {\sqrt {1+x^2}}) = 1$.

Prove that :

$(x+ {\sqrt{1+x^2}} ) ( y+ {\sqrt {1+y^2}}) = 1$.

I tried taking $x=y$. It simplifies everything a lot. But I'm not able to progress when both $x$ and $y$ are in the same equation.

Comment: Have you tried expanding?  That is, have you tried multiplying it out?  $(A+B)(C+D)=AC+AD+BC+BD$

Comment: That does not seem to help a lot ... at least for me.

Comment: Rationalizing might help.

Comment: @guest, how would you rationalize this?  I'm familiar with rationalizing e.g. complex numbers but not sure what you mean in this context.

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(x%2B%20%7B%5Csqrt%7B1%2Bx%5E2%7D%7D%20)%20(%20y%2B%20%7B%5Csqrt%20%7B1%2By%5E2%7D%7D)%20%3D%201%24&p=1) you can find some questoins which might be related: [Prove that if $({x+\sqrt{x^2+1}})({y+\sqrt{y^2+1}})=1$ then $x+y=0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1118742) and [$\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\left(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)=1$. Find $(x+y)$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1794502).

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartinSleziak

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $x =\sinh(a), y=\sinh(b)$.

Then
$$(\sinh(a)+\cosh(b)) (\cosh(a) +\sinh(b))=1 \\
\sinh(a)\cosh(a)+\sinh(b)\cosh(b)+\cosh(a)\cosh(b)+\sinh(a)\sinh(b)=1 \\
\sinh(a+b)+\cosh(a+b)=1
$$

Now,
$$1=\cosh^2(a+b)-\sinh^2(a+b)=\left( \sinh(a+b)+\cosh(a+b)\right)\left( \cosh(a+b)-\sinh(a+b)\right) \\=\left( \cosh(a+b)-\sinh(a+b)\right)$$
Therefore
$$\sinh(a+b)+\cosh(a+b)=1\\
 \cosh(a+b)-\sinh(a+b)=1$$
 and hence 
$$\cosh(a+b)=1 \\
\sinh(a+b)=0$$

which proves that $a+b=0$.

Therefore $y=-x$.

From here it is trivial.

Comment: I don't know much about hyperbolic functions, but there is one thing for sure : your result "$y= - x$" proves that $y^2 = x^2$, which helps in substituting $y^2$ for $x^2$ in the first equation to yield the second equation.

Comment: Briliant idea!!

Comment: @QUANTUM You can alternately try the parametrisation $x=\tan(a), y=\tan(b)$ and try to reduce it. I used the $\sinh(a), \cosh(a)$ as the identities involving hyperbolic sin and cos are usually known better than the ones involving secant and tangent.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Write $$x = \frac{1}{2}(s-\frac{1}{s})\\
y = \frac{1}{2}(t-\frac{1}{t})$$
with $s$, $t>0$. [Then](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28%20%28s-1%2Fs%29%2F2%20%2B%20%28t%2B1%2Ft%29%2F2%29%28%20%28t-1%2Ft%29%2F2%20%2B%20%28s%2B1%2Fs%29%2F2%20%29-1%20%29-%28%20s%20t%20-%201%29%20%28s%20t%20%28%20s%2Bt%29%5E2%20%2B%20%28s-t%29%5E2%20%29%2F%284%20s%5E2%20t%5E2%29)

$$( x+ \sqrt{1+y^2})(y + \sqrt{1+x^2}) -1 = (s t -1) \frac { s t (s+t)^2 + (s-t)^2}{ 4 s^2 t^2}$$